# How can we ensure real time currency converter in paypal standard payment gateway on the site?

Tags: wordpress, payment-gateway

An e-commerce website uses wp-ecommerce plugin on website. Local Currency used in INR. Bill generated is in $ but currency rate used in not real time. How to ensure this.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into integrating an exchange rates API such as https://openexchangerates.org/, there might be a plugin available that already does this for wp-ecommerce.